# Powershell Script Only Works With Explicit Parameter Declaration

Tags: powershell, sharepoint

I wrote the below script for checking out an item in SharePoint:

```
#######################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################
# Check out - Checks out a file saved in the given directory
#######################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################
Param (
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [string]$site,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [string]$listName,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [string]$doc
)

Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.Sharepoint.Powershell

$spWeb = Get-SPWeb $site
$list = $spWeb.Lists |? {$_.Title -eq $listName}

ForEach ($item in $list.Items) {
    $itemFile = $item.File
    if($itemFile.CheckOutStatus -eq "none" -and $itemFile.Name -eq $doc) {
        try {         
            $itemFile.CheckOut()
            Write-Host "Item checked out" -BackgroundColor Green
        } catch {Write-Host "Error when checking in item" -BackgroundColor Red}
    }
}
```

After removing the `Param` block and explicitly declaring the parameters, I am able to run this script without any issues whatsoever. By explicitly declaring I mean at the top of the script I set `$site = http://mysite/mypage` etc

However, as soon as I added the `Param` block, the script no longer works.

I call it like this:

`\\path\to\file\script.ps1 -site http://mysite/mypage -list "Name of List" -doc "name of doc"` from a powershell console.

And there is **no output** in the console, and the file is not checked out.

I have created other scripts using the same Param setup and these work fine, but for some reason this script only works if I declare the params inside the script .... Any advice is much appreciated!

Comment: What do you mean "removing the param block and explicitly declaring the parameters"?   You need a param block to have parameters to a script (without using $args).

Comment: @MikeShepard he explained what he meant by that (creating a variable with the same name and assigning it a value rather than accepting it as a parameter)

Comment: @Bassie could you debug this and see what your parameter values are during execution? You can load the script in ISE, set breakpoints, and then in the ISE console you can call the script with the parameters and the breakpoints will work. Then you can use the console to see variables in the execution context and you can step through the code to better see what's going on.

Comment: @briantist My bad...I somehow skipped over that.  Agree that debugging is the answer.

Comment: Did you mistype -list ? In your params declaration it says $listname , hence you should call your script with -listname "My list name"

Comment: @CmdrTchort PS will resolve `-list` to `-listname`.

Comment: @Bassie debugging in ISE is quick and easy. However another debugging approach is to dot source the script: `. \\path\to\file\script.ps1 -site http://mysite/mypage -list "Name of List" -doc "name of doc"` and then look at the script's variables after the script is run. `$spweb, $list, etc.` should all have values after the script runs. You can check that they have the right values. Based on those values you can get a good idea what's going on in the script. Yet another approach is: `set-psdebug -trace 1`, which will display each line executed of all scripts until turned off.